# How to use a variable form a function in another function in the same controller in laravel 8

Tags: controller, laravel-8

I got the mobile number from employee i have to pass the $mobile variable in department function. so how can I use a variable of a function in another Request type function.

```
public function employee($id){
    $result= Employee::where('emp_id',$id)->get();
    $mobile= $result[0]['mobile'];
}
public function department(Request $request){

    $req= new Department
    $req->name= $request->name;
    $req->emp_id=$request->eid;
    $req->emp_mobile=$mobile //the variable want to pass
    $req->save();
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on employee function, add this code

```
public function employee($id){
    $result= Employee::where('emp_id',$id)->get();
    $mobile= $result[0]['mobile'];
    return $mobile;
}
```

on department function:

```
public function department(Request $request){
    $req= new Department
    $req->name= $request->name;
    $req->emp_id=$request->eid;
    $req->emp_mobile = $this->employee($request->eid);
    $req->save();
}
```